# ¿Cómo utilizar el valor de una variable para obtener una propiedad de un objeto?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, poo, redux

[Estoy realizando un aplicación con react y redux]

El problema ocurre una vez que obtengo el valor que recibo como argumento en la url:
ya que obtengo el valor sin problemas, LO que Ocurre es que el valor que recibo es el nombre de una propiedad que tengo dentro de mi store de redux:
ejemplo:

1. el valor del argumento recibido por  url es: hamburguesa
2. luego yo almaceno este valor en una variable (llamada parametro)
3. dentro de mi store tengo una propiedad que se llama hamburguesa
4. Cuando quiero obtener este valor ejecutando store . parametro me devuelve undefined
5. Esto no ocurre cuando hago store . hamburguesa ya que obtengo el valor sin problemas:
   Codigo :

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
function CategoriesCreativeScreen ( {match, estado,history}){
 const parametro = match.params.cat; // igual a mascota
 console.log(estado.parametro);// undefined
 console.log(estado.mascota); //obtengo el valor sin problemas
    return (
        <>
        <h2>Testeando</h2>
        </>
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Solo debes acceder a la propiedad con []

```
estado[parametro]
```

Aqui un ejemplo:

```js
const obj = {
   a: 1,
   b: 2,
   c: 3
}

const propiedad = "c";

console.log("El cvalor de la propiedad "+ propiedad + " es " + obj[propiedad]);
```

Comment: sigue siendo undefined el valor al igual que con estado.parametro

Comment: No tiene sentido... Estás seguro que `estado.hamburguesa` si tiene un valor? podrías añadir a tu pregunta que obtienes con `console.log(estado)` y que obtienes con `console.log(estado["hamburguesa"])`